# Subset with vector specifying columns to drop

Tags: r, subset

Let's say, we have a simple data frame like

```
df <-read.table(text="
colA colB colC colD
1    2    3    4
5    6    7    8
",header=TRUE,sep="")
```

It has often been explained that one can store the names of columns to be kept in a vector itself:

```
rows_to_select <- c("colA", "colB")
```

Subsetting with `subset(df, select=rows_to_select)` yields the expected outcome.

But why can't I simply invert the keep-sign by putting a minus in front, i.e. `subset(df, select=-rows_to_select)`? It gives the error `Error in -keep : invalid argument to unary operator Calls: subset -> subset.data.frame -> eval -> eval`.

However, `subset(df, select=-c(colA, colB))` works. Do I always have to employ setdiff, e.g. `keep <- setdiff(names(df), rows_to_select)` so that I can `subset(df, select=keep)`?

Comment: `subset(df, select = -xtfrm(rows_to_select))`

Comment: @rawr That doesn't seem to work with `rows_to_select <- c("colB", "colC")`

Comment: ya.. one would need to `rows_to_select <- factor(c("colB", "colC"), levels = colnames(df))` that if one so desired @MrFlick

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use a minus sign with a character vector.  But you can use one with a numeric index vector.  Furthermore, you'd be better-off using `[`-type subsetting.

To get an index, we can use `which`.

```
> rows <- c("colA", "colB")
> df[, -which(names(df) %in% rows)]
#   colC colD
# 1    3    4
# 2    7    8
```

Comment: Why is this better? Is it faster?

Comment: @user3621464 - It's not better, not worse.  They time about the same.  I was just trying to point out why you were having problems with negative indexing on a character vector.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't precise enough. I referred to your part "you'd be better-off using [-type subsetting." Why am I better off using `[` instead of `$`?

Comment: I meant as opposed to using `subset`

Comment: Ah okay. But why is `[` better than `subset()`?

Comment: @user3621464 - I will refer you to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset) for an answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` package offers your way of subsetting data.

```
v1 <- 1:10
v2 <- 11:20
v3 <- rep(c("ana", "bob"), each = 5)
v4 <- letters[1:10]

foo <- data.frame(v1,v2,v3, v4, stringsAsFactors=F)

# Remove column v2 and v3
select(foo, -c(v2:v3))

#   v1 v4
#1   1  a
#2   2  b
#3   3  c
#4   4  d
#5   5  e
#6   6  f
#7   7  g
#8   8  h
#9   9  i
#10 10  j
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several different ways you could accomplish this, and you are not limited to just the `subset` function. For example,

```
Df <- data.frame(
  colA=1:4,
  colB=5:8,
  colC=9:12,
  colD=13:16)
##
rows_to_select <- c("colA", "colB")
##
> Df[,!(names(Df) %in% rows_to_select)]
  colC colD
1    9   13
2   10   14
3   11   15
4   12   16
```

Subsetting `data.frame`s using `[` is also more efficient than calling `subset()`. But to address your question of

> why can't I simply invert the keep-sign by putting a minus in front

that is just a result of R's language structure.

Comment: More efficient means faster?